# Difference between Outlook.MailItem.EntryID and Mapi32.dll MessageID

Tags: outlook, vbo, mapi

I need to do some functionality from outlook VBO. Let say i'm downloading attachments from the outlook.mailitem. So I do save those files by prepending OutLook.MailItem.EntryID where EntryID is unique for each Email.

Now, I have another functionality or application that uses Mapi32.dll and that need to access the Files. So I used the MessageID property to get the files, but the problem is when I retrieve MessageID property from the Mapi32.dll it returns something like AAAAAKHslFt5unxKlnJ80RmsEX8HAEYxSGm4YvNPlCN7Kj9X/A8AAAAAAQwAAEYxSGm4YvNPlCN7Kj9X/A8AAOy+SWQAAA

but the EntryID from Outlook is 1DCBEE7832C89149AFAEBC41B53EAB85

I think both EntryID and MessageID are same, but is that encrypted from MapiEx? How can I decrypt it to get original EntryID ? Or is there any other common property between Outlook.MailItem object and Mapi32.dll MailMessage object that I can use to share information between two tool ?

Comment: I don't understand where you're getting that base 64 string from. Can you share some of your "mapi32.dll" code?

Answer (score 0):

The former looks like a base64 encoded entry id. The latter looks weird - entry ids usually start with 4 binary 0's (eight "0"s in the hex notation).